# Texworks freezes at midnight

Tags: texworks

At the stroke of midnight each evening, as long as it is open, whether I be working on a document or letting it sit idle, TeXworks (ver. 0.6.2) becomes unresponsive at and suddenly takes up an enormous amount of CPU. That is, a "(Not Responding)" label appears next to the name of the document on the top bar, and everything is paled out slightly. I always have to force it to shut down. Is there a reason this happens, and also a fix for it, short of uninstalling and re-installing the newer version (0.6.3)? It's never happened at any other time (at which one is at the computer).

Comment: Most probable explanation: witching hour

Comment: Werewolf.......

Comment: The sun shines on the other side of the planet, no wonder that things freeze. ;-)

Comment: Cinderella syndrome? Look for a crystal shoe somewhere nearby. `;-)` What OS are you on?

Comment: There are different flavours of TeXworks 0.6.2 e.g. the one that comes with MiKTeX is different from the one that comes with tex live is different from the core one and many other ports etc. I have not seen behaviour as you describe however (I just cant resist saying I don't feed the gremlins at midnight) I have not been looking for such an issue. generally there are no time related commands in texworksbut have you got any backup scripts active that could be trying to modify files on a schedule (antivirus/update/defrag/chron job etc)

Comment: Are there any news here? Have you checked if the problem persists in the latest version of TeXworks? If so, perhaps open an issue on the [TeXworks GitHub site](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues).